# How to Transfer Magento database from one hosting account to another

Tags: magento-1.9, database

During transferring Magento Database from one hosting account to another, we have to add several options in the MySQL backup file prior to uploading it.

Why the following should be added at the beginning of the SQL file? Would you please explain the reason and some technical details?

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT;
SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS;
SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION;
SET NAMES utf8;
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0;
```

Also the reason of adding these options at the end of the file.

```
SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT;
SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS;
SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION;
SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES;
```

is this method standard? any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because Magento use foreign key constraints to certify database integrity.

The built-in backup function inserts special statements in the .sql file by default to skip foreign key checks so If we backup the database using mysqldump, these special statements will be missing.

To avoid `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` error we have to add those special statements by ourselves.

These special statements will add logical structure and integrity of the database if not the .sql file doesn't have any structure (only tables row by row).

So there are two ways to make backup and restore them:

- Magento Built-in Backup (Admin > System > Tools > Backup)
- mysqldump or phpMyAdmin or Navicat (+ adding the below statements)

at the beginning of the .sql file

```
SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT;
SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS;
SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION;
SET NAMES utf8;
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0;
```

at the end of the .sql file

```
SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT;
SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS;
SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION;
SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES;
```

[Restoring a backup of a Magento database](https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/m1wiki/pages/14024834/Restoring+a+backup+of+a+Magento+database)

Comment: You can also accept your own answer :)